# Synonym for "Money doesn't grow on trees"

Tags: phrase-requests

What would be a more sophisticated phrase for "money does not grow on trees"

Thanks in advance!

Comment: *There's no such thing as free lunch* or *you don't get something for nothing*.

Comment: I've retagged the question. Please see the question checklist at the end of the [tag info](https://english.stackexchange.com/tags/phrase-requests/info). This sort of question needs quite a lot of information to get you **just** the right answer: otherwise it's merely a guessing game where every answer gets "No, not that": we need to know your criteria.

Comment: I have never before heard anyone say "money *does not* grow on trees": it's usually "doesn't" - so you've already made it more sophisticated.

Comment: What do you mean be *sophisticated*? If *money doesn't grow on trees* doesn't sound sophisticated to you, then I doubt any idiom would. You could say ***money is a scarce commodity***. You might consider that "sophisticated" because it's not an idiom. But is that what you want?

Comment: I wonder if this is a 'failed metaphor'? / 'You need to learn the value of money.'